# access content from higher folders

Tags: html, hyperlink, indexing, image

If I have the following index

```
[folder]Public_HTML
       ↳[folder]img
               ↳[file]logo.png
       ↳[file]index.html
       ↳[folder]contact
               ↳[file]index.html
```

From the folder titled img I can add the file logo.png to the index.html under the folder public_HTML by using the HTML `<img src="img/logo.png"/>` but how could I access this img file from the index.html filed under the folder titled contact without requiring to add the domain name in front for e.g http://mydomain.com/img/logo.png. or is this the only way it can be accessed from the contact folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use double dots to move one folder up:
< img src="../img/logo.png" />

If you want to move up more folder, it could look like: 
< img src="../../img/logo.png"/>

Comment: In combination with CharlesB's suggestion of starting with a slash, you can fit any situation, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="/img/logo.png"/>`. Adding a slash at the beginning makes the path absolute.